# C++ templated function creation with raw or smart pointer gets different results

Tags: c++, class, templates

Lets say I have : (this class Is OK)

```
class CCheckSystemEndianess
{
private:
    int i;
    char checker[sizeof(int)];
public:
    CCheckSystemEndianess() : i(1) { }
    bool isLittleEndian()   { return (checker[0] != 0); }
};
```

But this one acts strange

```
template <bool checker>
class CEndian
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    T swapEndianess (const T& value)
    {
        if (CCheckSystemEndianess().isLittleEndian() == checker)
        {
            return value;
        }
.................
```

The main problem is that if I create  CEndian different ways I get different results with CCheckSystemEndianess().isLittleEndian()

For ex.

```
CEndian<false> *p_endian = new CEndian<false>();
```

then this line becomes

```
CcheckSystemEndianess().isLittleEndian() = false
```

But if I create CEndian like this

```
std::unique_ptr<CEndian<false> > p_endian (new Cendian<false>());
```

then this line becomes
    CcheckSystemEndianess().isLittleEndian() = true.

And yes If I create CCheckSystemEndianes inside CEndian class everything goes OK

```
template <typename T>
T swapEndianess (const T& value)
{
   std::unique_ptr<CCheckSystemEndianess> endianCheck(newCCheckSystemEndianess);
```

checkSystemEndianess().isLittleEndian() both ways with smart and with raw pointer gets true....

I am confused there a bit ..

Edit:
Thanks to Cubbi for pointing out that CCheckSystemEndianess has to be union not class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CCheckSystemEndianess, `i`, and `checker` are two unrelated objects. The value `1` written to `i` by the constructor has no bearing on the contents of `checker` which remain uninitialized.

Perhaps your intent was to make a union?

Comment: As a matter of fact yes. I was thinking about union but made class.